# How to detect/monitor the hosts/urls being accessed?

Tags: networking, monitoring, network-monitoring

Does anyone know about software that can detect or monitor host / url are being accessed by ubuntu? I want to see what host/url are beeing accessed by installed software or by my internet browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For just watching general traffic destinations, I like using *iftop*:

```
sudo iftop
```

It'll show a live report with speeds, through-put, etc:

```
                25.0Kb          50.0Kb          75.0Kb          100Kb      125Kb
└───────────────┴───────────────┴───────────────┴───────────────┴───────────────
system.outflux.net         => wildcard-edge-launchpad-n  3.49Kb  3.94Kb  3.94Kb
                           <=                            3.38Kb  10.3Kb  10.3Kb
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
TX:             cumm:  71.3KB   peak:    154Kb  rates:    154Kb  95.0Kb  95.0Kb
RX:                    47.6KB            126Kb            126Kb  63.4Kb  63.4Kb
TOTAL:                  119KB            280Kb            280Kb   158Kb   158Kb
```

Note that `iftop` will choose the first network interface it finds to monitor (usually `eth0` for your ethernet cable). If you'd like it to listen to another interface, like your wireless card, you can list valid interfaces with `ifconfig`, and then call `iftop -i [interface_name]`.

For watching your browser, I recommend the [Tamper Data](http://tamperdata.mozdev.org/) extension for Firefox. Opening its window will show you all the active and historical requests:

[image]

Comment: [HttpFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/httpfox/) provides similar monitor functionality as Tamper Data, without methods for "tampering" (modifying) the data.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, you can set up a http proxy software (like squid) and using that: proxy server will log accesses. Another solution: use netfilter of the linux kernel (with `iptables`) to log network connections. If you use the `ULOG` target, with `ulogd` daemon you can use different log file, `LOG` will use the kernel log, which is not so nice in my opinion since other messages go there too which are produced by the kernel.

Comment: is there any real time application (GUI or Console), so I don't need to open the log file?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean about "real time" application. If you have a log file, you can see its content "real time" in terminal like `tail -f /var/log/ulog/syslogemu.log` (that's ulogd default log file), then you will see "real time". But you have some "not so perfect" solutions, like you can use `netstat -na` to see the actual network connections, of `iftop` (from package `iftop`) to see a top like interface with the current connections. I think even the nicest GUI applications for this (if exits) uses log file or other information sources anyway, ulogd is via netlink sockets for example

Comment: Also for nice GUI solution you can use softwares like conky http://conky.sourceforge.net/ which is a system monitor, you can configure it to show log files as well among many other things.

Comment: I forgot to mention: of course netfilter logging etc won't log the URL itself just the IP of the target web server for example. For real HTTP level logging usage of some http proxy is needed, it's not a problem if your apps can't do proxy: you can use transparent proxy as well: apps can't even know they use proxy. And iftop is a general "real time" traffic monitoring tool, it's not strictly http related of course, it was only an example. Anyway I hope I could give you some pointers ....